# OK to skip slash before query string?

Tags: url, query-string

Is it safe to always skip the trailing slash when appending a query string?

That is, can I use

```
http://example.com?querystring
```

instead of:

```
http://example.com/?querystring
```

? All webhosts I've used support this but is it safe to assume that all server environments will support this method? Is it standard?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the server. If you add a `Location` header to a request, it will send that to the client, who will be responsible in properly understanding what your original intent was. The client will _try_ to "fix" your URL, by adding the slash at the root location, if that's what it was designed to do. All requests sent by any browser, modern or not, will always begin with `/`, regardless of what you enter into the URL bar.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**No. It is not correct to skip the slash.** It *may* work modern browsers: however, that does not make it correct.

See [RFC1738 - URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) and
[RFC2396 - URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396).

The format per RFC1738 (I have excluded the schema format here):

> > //<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<url-path>

And it goes on to note that:

> > ...the "/" between the host (or port) and the url-path is NOT part of the url-path.

In this case the "?" is part of the url-path which

> > ...depends on the scheme being used, as does the manner in which it is interpreted.

Also note that, per specification, it is perfectly valid to *omit* "/url-path" -- note that the "/" has been explicit included in this case.

Thus, "foo.com?bar" is invalid because there is no "/" before the url-path.

Comment: -1; this answer is almost completely wrong. It cites specs from the 1990s that were already years obsolete at the time that this answer was written, and while it correctly interprets RFC 1738 as requiring the slash, it cites RFC 2396 without noticing that RFC 2396 explicitly allows the slash to be omitted. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42193734/1709587) for a detailed analysis of what both those specs say, as well as the more RFC 3986 and WhatWG URL Living Standard, both of which also allow the slash to be omitted.

Comment: As an aside, people, please, *please*, ***please*** cite the HTML versions of the IETF's RFCs (e.g. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738), not the text ones (e.g. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt). Besides being prettier and easier to navigate, they contain a header bar that clearly marks whether the spec is obsolete. I've edited this answer to reference the HTML versions now, but if the answerer here had read (and linked to) them in the first place, there's no way that it would've taken 7 years for anyone to notice that this answer is citing a spec that had been obsolete since 2005.

Comment: Let me just state a counter example. YouTube links don't have a '/' before '?'. Actually OP is asking about whether servers treat them as equivalent, not about browsers. In any case, consider updating your answer with the updated spec.

Comment: @KevinLee I'm afraid that there ain't much point suggesting that the author update this answer - their account no longer exists.

Comment: @MarkAmery thank you for [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617058/ok-to-skip-slash-before-query-string/42193734#42193734). It is unfortunate that this wrong one remains as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 132):

As a matter of modern spec, ***yes*, it is permissible to skip the slash**, contrary to what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1617074/1709587) here claims.

Although the accepted answer correctly quotes RFC 1738 (released over 20 years ago!), it wrongly claims that RFC 2396 (released in 1998) requires the slash, and neglects that *both* of those specs have in turn been obsoleted by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), released in 2005 (still several years before the accepted answer was written) and more recently by the [WhatWG URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org), both of which allow the slash to be omitted.

Let's consider each of these specs in turn, from earliest to latest:

---

#### [*RFC 1738: Uniform Resource Locators (URL)*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) (released in 1994)

Implicitly requires the slash to be included by [specifying that it *may* be omitted *if* the URL contains neither a path nor a query string](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.3) (called a `searchpart`, here). Bolding below is mine:

> An HTTP URL takes the form:
>
> ```
> http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>
> ```
>
> where `<host>` and `<port>` are as described in [Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.1). If :`<port>`
> is omitted, the port defaults to 80.  No user name or password is
> allowed.  `<path>` is an HTTP selector, and `<searchpart>` is a query
> string. The `<path>` is optional, as is the `<searchpart>` and its
> preceding "?". **If neither `<path>` nor `<searchpart>` is present, the "/"
> may also be omitted.**

---

#### *[RFC 2396: Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396)* (released in 1998; "updates" RFC 1738)

Here it is acceptable to omit the slash. This RFC legalises some weird URL syntaxes that don't have a double-slash after the scheme, but if we ignore those (they're the ones with an `opaque_part` in the spec's [BNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#appendix-A)) and stick to URLs that contain a host, then we find that an `absoluteURI` is defined like this...

> ```
> absoluteURI   = scheme ":" ( hier_part | opaque_part )
> ```

and that a `hier_part` looks like this:

> ```
> hier_part     = ( net_path | abs_path ) [ "?" query ]
> ```

and that a `net_path` looks like this:

> ```
> net_path      = "//" authority [ abs_path ]
> ```

where an `abs_path` is in turn defined to start with a slash. Note that the `abs_path` is *optional* in the grammar above - that means that a URL of the form `scheme://authority?query` is completely legal.

The motivation for this change is hinted at in appendix [G.2. Modifications from both RFC 1738 and RFC 1808](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#appendix-G.2):

> The question-mark "?" character was removed from the set of allowed
> characters for the userinfo in the authority component, since testing
> showed that many applications treat it as reserved for separating the
> query component from the rest of the URI.

In other words - code in the real world was assuming that the first question mark in a URL, anywhere, marked the beginning of a query string, and so the spec was pragmatically updated to align with reality.

---

#### [*RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (released in 2005; "obsoletes" RFC 2396)

Again, it is permissible to omit the slash. The spec expresses this by saying that a "path" is required in every URI that contains an authority (host), and that path must *either* begin with a slash *or* consist of no characters:

> [3.  Syntax Components](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3)
>
> The generic URI syntax consists of a hierarchical sequence of
> components referred to as the scheme, authority, path, query, and
> fragment.
>
> ```
> URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
>
> hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
>             / path-absolute
>             / path-rootless
>             / path-empty
> ```
>
> The scheme and path components are required, though the path may be
> empty (no characters).  When authority is present, the path must
> either be empty or begin with a slash ("/") character.

For completeness, note that `path-abempty` is later defined thus:

> ```
> path-abempty  = *( "/" segment )
> ```

This does indeed permit it contain no characters.

---

#### [*URL Standard*](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/) by WhatWG (a living standard under active maintenance, first created in 2012, with the goal of obsoleting RFC 3986)

Again, omitting the slash is acceptable, although this time we have no BNF to look at but instead need to read lots of prose.

[Section 4.3](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-writing) tells us:

> An [absolute-URL string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#absolute-url-string) must be one of the following
>
> - a [URL-scheme string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-scheme-string) that is an [ASCII case-insensitive](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-case-insensitive) match for a [special scheme](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#special-scheme) and not an [ASCII case-insensitive](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-case-insensitive) match for "`file`", followed by "`:`" and a [scheme-relative-special-URL string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#scheme-relative-special-url-string)
> - a [URL-scheme string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-scheme-string) that is *not* an [ASCII case-insensitive](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-case-insensitive) match for a [special scheme](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#special-scheme), followed by ":" and a [relative-URL string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#relative-url-string)
> - a [URL-scheme string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-scheme-string) that is an [ASCII case-insensitive](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-case-insensitive) match for "file", followed by ":" and a [scheme-relative-file-URL string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#scheme-relative-file-url-string)
>
> any optionally followed by "?" and a URL-query string.

Since HTTP and HTTPS are [special schemes](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#special-scheme), any HTTP or HTTPS URL must satisfy the first of those three options - that is, `http:` or `https:` followed by a [scheme-relative-special-URL string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#scheme-relative-special-url-string), which:

> must be "`//`", followed by a [valid host string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#valid-host-string), optionally followed by "`:`" and a [URL-port string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-port-string), optionally followed by a [path-absolute-URL string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#path-absolute-url-string).

A [path-absolute-URL string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#path-absolute-url-string) is defined to start with a slash, but is explicitly optional in the definition of an absolute-URL string above; thus, it is permissible to go straight from the host to the "`?`" and query string, and so URLs like `http://example.com?query` are legal.

---

Of course, none of this provides a cast-iron guarantee that every web server or HTTP library will accept such URLs, nor that they will treat them as semantically equivalent to a URL that contains the slash. But as far as *spec* goes, skipping the slash is completely legal.

Comment: (Unfortunately) browsers (such as Chrome), add a slash before the `?` in the address bar: for example [https://stackoverflow.com?test](https://stackoverflow.com?test) is replaced with [https://stackoverflow.com/?test](https://stackoverflow.com/?test) when loading the page. Can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Does it matter if a page is a directory or a  file ?   from the perspective of SEO ?

Answer (score 7):

Adding to the accepted answer with some more information I found after researching this problem:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396

> The authority component is preceded by a double slash "//" and is terminated by the next slash "/", question-mark "?", or by the end of the URI.  Within the authority component, the characters ";", ":", "@", "?", and "/" are reserved

Based on this statement, the question-mark should indicate the end of the authority component, with or without the slash.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738 (tags replaced)

> The {path} is optional, as is the {searchpart} and its preceding "?". If neither {path} nor {searchpart} is present, the "/" may also be omitted.

However, this statement says that the trailing slash can only be omitted if both the path and searchpart are not preset.

In the real world, I've previously been able to omit a trailing slash before a query value, but recently found a situation were that falls down.  If you have a query such as this http://my.domain.com?do=something, and you view an html page in Internet Explorer, the link is *fixed* by IE.  If you then click File, Send, Page by e-mail..., the link is added to the email with an invalid format.  The issues vary by the content of the query value but we were able to create invalid URLs.

In summary, it ***should*** work, but falls down in edge cases.

Comment: Another edge case: I was getting a bunch of 301 Redirects when using AJAX to request data from a REST API... until I used a trailing slash (preceding the query parameter). I had never seen that URL format before, but the added slash means I'm no longer getting those 301 Redirects. In this case the URL pattern was http://server.dsl/endpoint/id/?q=something

Comment: @Majorie, that sounds like the REST API you were calling was not properly handling your request structure and was handling the id as controller mapping rather than an endpoint.  Either way it is a good example of a potential behavior change based on what would appear to be an optional URL structure.

Comment: This answer (unlike the accepted answer) correctly interprets RFC 2396 and notes that RFC 1738 requires the slash while RFC 2396 does not. However (like the accepted answer) it still fails to notice that RFC 2396 is a long-obsolete RFC, replaced by [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) in January 2005, almost a decade before this answer was written.

Answer (score 4):

It is *not* safe to assume that. Web servers and self-contained web applications typically inspect the URL provided in the request, but there is no guarantee that they will treat `/abc` equal to `/abc/`. Web servers and self-contained web applications can do *whatever they like* with the information gleaned from the URL, and it will not necessarily be what you expect. You will have to find out what the convention is for the particular URL in question.

Note, of course, that most web servers and web application frameworks try hard to accept all sorts of inputs and deal with them appropriately. Therefore, in most cases, the web server or self-contained web application will treat `/abc` equal to `/abc/`. But remember, because the server can do whatever it likes with the path, that this is simply a generic observation with potentially numerous exceptions.

Comment: It's impossible to fire that kind of request to a web server (using a browser.) All HTTP requests have to begin with /, and there's no browser that will get that wrong. Even if Google Chrome will accept that URL, it will always make the request starting with / to the server.

Comment: @MilosIvanovic The point is regarding the trailing slash. I don't think he is disputing about the beginning /.

Answer (score 0):

can use query string in between also below is example

/rest/mainfolder/subfolder?jsonFormat=stream&/value1/value2