# TinkerPop3 rest test via browser

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am getting the valid response while made curl request :

```
bin/gremlin-server.bat conf/gremlin-server-rest-modern.yaml

curl "http://localhost:8182?gremlin=100-1"
curl "http://localhost:8182?gremlin=g.V()"
```

But via browser I am getting the below massage :

```
{"message":"no gremlin script supplied"}
```

Also tried as below but no result:

```
http://localhost:8182/gremlin?script=g.V()
http://localhost:8182/graphs/tinkergraph/tp/gremlin?script=g.traversal().V()
http://localhost:8182/graphs/tinkergraph/tp/gremlin?script=g.V()
```

Any suggestion on what is the valid way of passing script via browser.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is a "bug" exactly, but Gremlin Server didn't respect very complex `ACCEPT` headers.  For example, when I try to resolve one of your first two URLs in Chrome, I get:

```
{
  message: "no serializer for requested Accept header: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
}
```

By default, Gremlin Server doesn't support that `ACCEPT`.  If the browser had requested `application/json` or simply `*.*` it would work.  Note that `*.*` is present with quality `0.8`, but Gremlin Server wasn't parsing the header that way to determine that.  As a result, it couldn't find the serializer to properly deal with that.

There is no workaround for the browser that I know of.  I've created an issue to get this fixed:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP3-752

Answer (score 1):

I've also seen this error when I have forgotten to start cassandra before starting gremlin-server.

Comment: Thank you, my problem exactly.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was due to the presence of spaces in the request.

This worked;

```
curl http://localhost:8182/?gremlin="g.V().has('name','foody')"
```

but this didn't;

```
curl http://localhost:8182/?gremlin="g.V().has('name', 'foody')"
```

Try removing them from yours and they should work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer thanks to your question, so I will pitch for the right answer for @stacey-morgan:
You queried on the CLI:

```
curl "http://localhost:8182?gremlin=100-1"
```

Then you *may* have queried (as it is not clear from your question)

```
http://localhost:8182/gremlin?script=100-1
```

Or the others you have done, just as I was doing:

```
http://localhost:8182/gremlin?script=g.V()
```

You would get the error message. 
The correct way of doing it just paste the content of the "" from the curl command. So

```
http://localhost:8182?gremlin=100-1
```

Then similarly for your other queries:

```
http://localhost:8182/?gremlin=g.V()
http://localhost:8182/?gremlin=g.traversal().V()
```

Note: trailing slash [should](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1617058/2332101) be there though it works without it on my FF. That is HTTP.

Using: Ubuntu & Titan1.0.0-hadoop1.