# Flutter/ Parsing a part of url

Tags: flutter

So basically I have a QR code generator in the app, I already implemented a feature generating it with url, such as `domain.com/userid?=111`.
So, now I want QR code scanner to scan it and get only the id part of the user out of it, like it scanned the url example provided above, and then I just want to get '111' part to process.
How can I implement it?

Comment: Shouldn't your url be `domain.com?userid=111` instead of `domain.com/userid?=111`

Comment: @JideGuru, no it should be `domain.com/?userid=111`, read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1617074/1204153

Comment: Ignore my comment, both should work and I don't want to start a debate about it like on that thread :) Either way, we can both agree OP's URI is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Uri` queryParametersAll:

```dart
Uri url = Uri.parse('https://www.example.com/?userid=111');
print(url.queryParametersAll['userid'][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring method to get the part of it.

```
// Dart 2.6.1 

main() {
  String str = "domain.com/userid?=111";
  print(str.substring(str.indexOf("=")+1));
}
```