# Should I include a slash before a query for my WebAPI endpoint?

Tags: api, rest, restful-url, webapi

I'm creating API endpoints for my app. Which of the following endpoint format is more 'standard'? In the example below I will be returning user id 'john' from my users table.

```
https://localhost:33170/api/users?id=john
```

**OR**

```
https://localhost:33170/api/users/?id=john
```

---

FYI, the following endpoint will return all users:

```
https://localhost:33170/api/users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been determined that [it doesn't matter if the trailing slash is on or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42193734/1204153).

I don't know of any framework that treats either case differently... Those two routes are identical in every framework I have ever used.